# Pass variable data from Javascript to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a way for me to submit data collected and passed to a variable using javascript to a php page. 
I have a form that has input fields that are posted to a php file I am using a jquery function to serialize the form data and process it in php. However as well as the form data from the input fields I want to send data that I have collected and stored in a javascript variable and pick that up into a php variable so I can run a for loop.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>New User Registration</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="newUserHld">
  <table id="newUserFrmTbl">
   <form id="newUserFrm">
    <tr>
     <td><label id="firstnameLbl">First Name</label></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="firstname" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><label id="lastnameLbl">Last Name</label></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="lastname" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><label id="dobLbl">Date of Birth</label></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="dob" size="8" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><label id="positionLbl">Position</label></td>
     <td>
      <select size="1">
       <option>Select Option</option>
       <option> WFXM </option>
       <option>Operations Manager</option>
       <option>Assistant</option>
      
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><label id="usernameLbl">Username</label></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="username" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><label id="passwordLbl">Password</label></td>
     <td><input type="password" id="password" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><label id="payRateLbl">Pay Rate</label></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="payRate" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" id="createUsr" name="createUsr" value="Create User" /> </td> 
   </form>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div id="success">
 </div>
 <button type="button" onclick="getFrmElm()">Try it</button>
</body>
 <script>
  function getFrmElm (){
   var x = document.getElementById("newUserFrm");
   var txt = "";
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      txt = txt + x.elements[i].id + "<br>";
}
  formSubmit();
  
  }
  
  
function formSubmit(){
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'userreg.php',
    data:$('#newUserFrm').serialize(),
    success:function(response){
     $('#success').html(response);
    }
    });
   
 
    
   return false;
  }

  
 </script>
</html>




PHP FROM userreg




<?php
include_once "iud.php";
$db = connectDatabase();
        $formfields = test_input($_POST['txt'];
  $firstname=test_input($_POST['firstname']);
  $lastname=test_input($_POST['lastname']);
  
  
  
  $sql="INSERT INTO contacts(firstname, lastname) ";
  $sql .= "values (";
  $sql .= "'".$firstname."', '".$lastname."'";
  $sql .= ")";
  if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
   echo "Record Inserted";
   }else{
   echo "Insert failed"; 
   }

 mysqli_close($db);

 function test_input($data){
  
 $data=trim($data);
 $data=stripslashes($data);
 $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data; 
 }



?>
```

Basically I want to send the data from the form but also from the VAR txt with it.

Comment: write an ajax call and send data to php

Comment: @DhavalChheda the OP is using `AJAX`....

Comment: Not sure if this is a copy/paste error but you don't seem to close the function call `test_input($_POST['txt'];` It should be `test_input($_POST['txt']);` and you might want to place the function before (above) you try to call it.

Comment: You are right I was missing that closing but I just put that in as what I think it should do logicallly so I haven’t tried it yet I will do that and check.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your ajax to contain data Key.
Currently there are no key there.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'userreg.php',
    data: {
        firstName: $("#firstName").val(),
        lastName: $("#lastName").val(),
        // ... and so on until all the form element in here - then your PHP will work
    },
    success:function(response){
        $('#success').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Since I am using the form serialize method it sends the data without using a key: value method, but ideally I’d like to send the txt variable that contains a list of elements. Not the actual values which I send using serialize.

Answer (score 0):

[image]your missing name attribute in input field and if u user ajax need to link jquery library file in header. below code help to post your form data using ajax.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>New User Registration</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="newUserHld">
        <table id="newUserFrmTbl">
            <form id="newUserFrm" method="POST" >
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="firstnameLbl">First Name</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="firstname" size="20" name="firstname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="lastnameLbl">Last Name</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="lastname" size="20" name="lastname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="dobLbl">Date of Birth</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="dob" size="8" name="dob" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="positionLbl">Position</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <select size="1" name="positionLbl">
                            <option>Select Option</option>
                            <option> WFXM </option>
                            <option>Operations Manager</option>
                            <option>Assistant</option>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="usernameLbl">Username</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="username" size="20" name="username" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="passwordLbl">Password</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" id="password" size="20"  name="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="payRateLbl">Pay Rate</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="payRate" size="20"  name="payRate" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" id="createUsr" name="createUsr" value="Create User"  onclick="formSubmit(); return false;" />  </td>   
            </form>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="success">
    </div>
</body>
    <script>

function formSubmit(){
    alert($('#newUserFrm').serialize());
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'userreg.php',
                data:$('#newUserFrm').serialize(),
                    success:function(response){
                        $('#success').html(response);
                    }
                });



            return false;
        }


    </script>
</html>
```

and php File to check response.

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: The function that sends the data is in a function file linked it works to serialize the form but not the new bar txt that is data collected from the is of the labels. I want to serialize that Data as well as the form I put fields Data which works.

Comment: maybe I can accomplish the task using the key's from the serialize in the array.